# Vuetify Combobox multiselect with object

Tags: vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

My data source is :

```json
[
  {
    "display": "client",
    "value": "client"
  }, 
  {
    "display": "firstname",
    "value": "firstname"
  }, 
  {
    "display": "lastname",
    "value": "lastname"
  }
]
```

And I need to keep this format.

In my application I need the possibility of adding keys (like add tags), I use the combobox, and I can display the data.
But when adding a new element, it does not keep the object format.

This is my code:

```vue
  <v-combobox
    v-model="password.keys"
    label="Add keys"
    chips
    item-text="display"
    item-value="value"

    prepend-icon="filter_list"
    solo
    multiple
  >
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
      <v-chip
        :selected="data.selected"
        close
        @input="remove(data.item)"
      >
        <strong>{{ data.item.display }}</strong>&nbsp;
      </v-chip>
    </template>
  </v-combobox>
```

#### Text Only

[image: show the text only]

#### Full Object display

[image: full object display]

How can I add a new object while keeping the object format?

Comment: You can do this by "manually" create the object once a new element is added to `password.keys` array. To do this you could deep watch the object or add an event handler `@change` to your combobox and once change is triggered check for strings element inside the array and convert them to objects as you want

Comment: maybe the "value-comparator" is what i look for but i don't know how to use ithttps://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#combobox

Comment: Have `display` and `value` always the same value ?

Comment: Yes, for now the display and the value is the same

Answer (score 1):

```html
<v-combobox :return-object="false">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
      <v-chip
        :selected="data.selected"
        close
        @input="remove(data.item)"
      >
        <strong>{{ getItemText(data.item) }}</strong>&nbsp;
      </v-chip>
    </template>
</v-combobox>
```

```js
methods: {
        getItemText(val) {
            const item = this.tags.find((i) => i.value === val);
            return item ? item.text : "";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to watch the `v-model=password.keys` to return value as object as our items are array of objects.

```vuejs
    watch: {
        'password.keys' (val, prev) {
          if (val.length === prev.length) return

          this.password.keys = val.map(v => {
            if (typeof v === 'string') {
              v = {
                display: v,
                value: v
              }
              this.items.push(v)
            }

            return v
          })
        }
      }
```